# Facebook Javascript SDK: Friend Invitations Limit

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have an app on facebook with a secure canvas URL (still not published).

I'm inviting friends in the following manner:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: message, to: ids, onInvite);
```

Is there a limit to how many ids I can pass to that function?

I saw in the facbook documentation something about 20-50 limit depending on the browser.

From what I understand the limit is due to Facebook's SDK using GET requests, is there a way to get rid of that limit?

Comment: you should always let the user decide and forget about the "to" parameter. 20-50 (or even more) would be spam.

Comment: I have a custom multiple friend selector inside of my app.

Comment: still, why would you want to send that many friend requests? as i said, that´s spam.

Comment: it's not. take a look at other games, that's how it'd done.

Comment: "other games do it too" is not a good argument for mass sending app requests... ;)

Comment: The game allows the player to choose who to send to.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/multi-friend-selector/v2.2

Comment: well, in that case it´s ok. i thought you would want to mass-auto-send requests. still, 50 recipients should be more than enough for any serious game.

Comment: basically yes, but think about it from a developer's point of view - you'd like to allow the user to send as many invitations as possible. If he wants to, why not 1000 instead of 50?

Comment: problem is, many developers don´t care about spam and try to spam all their friends with their app requests. you always have to think about the end users and his friends. especially his friends ;)

Comment: true, these people always ruin it for the rest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official [Requests Dialog documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.2#invoking) states 50 as a maximum of recipients for request:

> By default, the sender is presented with a multi-friend selector allowing them to select a **maximum of 50 recipients**.

URL restrictions are only for older versions of Internet Explorer for non iframe version of dialog (ie: popup)

> Note: Due to URL length restrictions, the maximum number of recipients is 25 in Internet Explorer 7 or 8 when using a non-iframe dialog.

Comment: Note: There are restrictions on the maximum number of recipients you are able to specify via the 'to' field. Namely, **fewer than 50 friends** - doesn't that mean 49 or less?

Comment: @MaximLaco, I'm fairly sure 50 is the upper limit since in other places, like documentation for Android platform [`setTo`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder/#setTo) state is that way.